# Integrating $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{-8 (\theta - cos\lambda)^3}{(1-2\theta cos\lambda +\theta^2)^3}d\lambda$

Tags: integration, trigonometry

Can anyone help me with solving the following intergral.

\begin{align*}
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{-8 (\theta - cos\lambda)^3}{(1-2\theta cos\lambda +\theta^2)^3}d\lambda
\end{align*}

Any hints also appreciated.

Comment: For what stands $$\theta$$ here?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner $\theta$ is a real-valued parameter.

Comment: Your $\pi$ is riding another $\pi$. Either the integral should be over $(-1,1)$, or $\pi\lambda$ should be replaced with $\lambda$ - otherwise you won't get a closed-form answer.

Comment: For a method to choose, you can either use Fourier series, or dive into complex integration with a substitution $z=\exp(i\pi\lambda)$ (or $z=\exp(i\lambda)$).

Comment: @metamorphy You are correct. I have used the wrong formula. I'll update the post.

Comment: Mathematica gives $-\frac{2 \pi  \left(\left(7 \theta ^4-2 \theta ^2+1\right) \left| \theta +1\right| +(\theta -1) (\theta +1)^3 \left| \theta -1\right| \right)}{(\theta -1) \theta ^3 (\theta +1)^3 \left| \theta -1\right| }$ as an answer

Comment: @MikalaiParshutsich: it's a miracle but this _coincides_ with my answer %)

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\mmphyres}{\displaystyle\operatorname*{Res}}$
Substitution $z=e^{i\lambda}$ and the [residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem) give
$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\left(\frac{2\theta-2\cos\lambda}{1-2\theta\cos\lambda+\theta^2}\right)^3\,d\lambda=2\pi\begin{cases}\mmphyres_{z=0}f+\mmphyres_{z=\theta}f, & |\theta|<1 \\ \mmphyres_{z=0}f+\mmphyres_{z=1/\theta}f, & |\theta|>1\end{cases}$$
where $f(z)=\displaystyle\frac{1}{z}\left(\frac{1-2\theta z+z^2}{(\theta-z)(1-\theta z)}\right)^3$. Fairly boring calculations show that
$$\mmphyres_{z=0}f=\dfrac{1}{\theta^3},\quad\mmphyres_{z=1/\theta}f=-\mmphyres_{z=\theta}f=\frac{1}{\theta^3}+\frac{6\theta}{(1-\theta^2)^2}.$$